# How does the Spark executor and driver share data back and forth? Not the result of the task, but the data itself

Tags: java, apache-spark

So I have a spark application that reads DB records (lets say 1000 records), processes them, and writes a CSV file (with 1000 lines) out to the cloud Object storage. So three questions here:

1. Is DB read request sent to executors? If so in case of 1000 DB records, would each executor read partial DB data (example 500 records each) and send the records back to driver? Or does it write to a central cache and driver would read it from there?
2. Next step processing the DB records (fold job), is sent to 2 executors. Lets say each executor gets 500 records or so. Once the executor finishes processing its partition does it send all 500 processed (formatted) rows back to driver? Or does it write some central cache and driver gets it back? How is the data exchange happening between driver and executor happen?
3. Last step is the .save csvfile call in my main() function. In this code I am doing a reparition(1) with the idea that I will only save this file from one executor. If so, how is the data collected into this one executor. Remember earlier we had two executors process 500 records each. How is a total of 1000 records sent to one executor and gets saved into the object storage by one executor? how is the data collected from all executors shared into that one executor executing the .save?

   dataset.repartition(1)
   .write()
   .format("csv")
   .option("header", "true")
   .save(filepath);

If I dont do repartition(1), will the save happen from multiple executors and would it overwrite each other? I dont think there is a way we can specify the filename to be unique using spark. Do I have to save the file in temp and rename later and all that?

Are there any articles, youtube videos that will explain how data is distributed and collected or shared across executors? I can understand how .count() works. but how does .save work or how is large data results like millions of DB records or rows shared across executors? I have been looking for resources to read can't seem to find one that answers my questions. I am very new to spark, like 3 weeks new.